# What is meant by the assumption of statistical independence among sources in Independent Component Analysis?

Tags: time-series, independence, unsupervised-learning, independent-component-analysis

One of the underlying assumptions of independent component analysis (ICA) that I **consistently** see written is "statistical independence across the source signals". In the context of the classic cocktail party blind source separation problem, this would be interpreted as an assumption that the time series associated with the source signals are independent, which brings me to my question:

> What does it mean for time series of **single** observations to be statistically independent?

From my basic understanding of statistics, one interpretation of times series is a random vector. So, for example, a finite, discrete sampling of some source of acoustic sound can be thought of as : $\tau=\{x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n\}$ where $n$ is the total number of points comprising the sample (and $x_i$ represents the sound pressure at time point $i$). Further, each $x_i$ is effectively a realization of a random variable $X_i$.

The definition of statistical independence I am most familiar with applies to random variables...but I suspect it also applies to random vectors. If there are two source signals (in the context of the cocktail party), then I will have have $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$, which represent realizations of random vectors $T_1$ and $T_2$, where $T_1$ is comprised of realizations of random variables $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \cdots \alpha_n$and $T_2$ is comprised of realizations of random variables $\beta_1, \beta_2, \cdots \beta_n$. To show that $T_1$ and $T_2$ are statistically independent, I therefore need to show that $P(T_1 \cap T_2)=P(T_1)P(T_2)$. ...**and this is where I am confused**.

I only have $\tau_1$ (a single measurement of all possible samples of $T_1$) and $\tau_2$ (another single measurement of all possible samples of $T_2$). How can I deduce anything about the independent nature of $T_1$ and $T_2$ when I only have one sample for each random vector?

Am I misunderstanding something? I know that ICA methods essentially aim to *produce* estimates (of sources) that are 'maximally independent', but it's not clear to me how we even confirm in the first place that the source signals, *themselves*, are independent. Is the assumption about statistical independence more of a "hopefully, there is some prior knowledge you can leverage to justify the usage of this algorithm that has the sole purpose of producing maximally independent estimates of the sources?"